# How does this exponential equation add up?

Tags: exponential-function

[image]

Here is the equation. How do we add up and get such a value? I can convert to a non-rad value, but I can't understand how 0.327 or -1.18 is gotten

Comment: Don't you notice terms in geometric progression ?

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: I am sure that you know that $e^{nx}=(e^x)^n$. So consider $x=-j \frac{2 \pi}{8}$ with $n$ running from $0$ to $3$. Is it better ?

Comment: dam. i thought I would have to convert them all to their cos+jsin form, and then I would get the real and imag components and i could do the tan inverse etc.

Comment: i dont think your method will work to get the answer. there should be an easier way, some formula involved

Comment: No. Compute the sum of the four terms in geometric progression and then replace $e^{jy}$ by ....

Comment: In this case, just compute each term (the angles are multiples of $\pi/4$).

Comment: For the GP sum. I know a=(1/8) and n=(3), what about the r value is it (-j.(2pi/8))

Comment: I suppose it is $e^{-j 2\pi/8}$

Comment: That gives such a complicated sum that involves j and the real value in both terms. i can't split the imag away from the real.

Comment: so I am an idiot. calculators are apparently allowed and my calculator does not support imag values. Thank you for your time though